# Add bounding box around a specific color in a white and black picture

Tags: python, image, opencv

How can I add a bounding box around a cluster of white pixels which form islands surrounded by black pixels? The image contains either 0 or 255 pixels.

```
sample = cv2.imread("image-jpg", flags=0)
_, white_black_image = cv2.threshold(sample , 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Here is the original image.

[image]

Here is how it should look like.

[image]

I believe it is an overkill to do a Deep Neural Network on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is a good candidate for using OpenCV and contours to find these shapes. Adrian has a good tutorial over on PyImageSearch for this - [OpenCV Tutorial: A Guide to Learn OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/19/opencv-tutorial-a-guide-to-learn-opencv/). Look for the section titled "Detecting and drawing contours".

After you've managed to get your shape contours, OpenCv allows you to place a bounding box around your contours. Look at the documentation here for it [Contour Features](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)  under the section "7. Bounding Rectangle".

Hopefully this does what you need more simply and quickly than a custom ML approach.